# Can you use the same IN-statement with the same values on multiple columns?

Tags: php, sql, mysqli

I´m trying to select all rows that contain `$sql_eingabe` in any column ('Vorname' and 'Name').

This first attempt works fine with just one column:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM Mitglied WHERE (Vorname) IN ($sql_eingabe)";
```

But when adding another column the query breaks

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM Mitglied WHERE (Vorname, Name) IN (($sql_eingabe),($sql_eingabe))";
```

and I get this warning:

```
mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in...
```

Comment: Why tagged with `php html` ?

Comment: Maybe I'm going crazy, but I don't see any difference between the first two code snipits you posted....

Comment: Your sql syntax is __invalid__

Comment: @u_mulder is correct, the `IN` statement doesn't work like this for multiple columns. You will need to use some kind of `EXISTS` statement, depending on the logic you want, you might just use two `IN` statements with an `OR`

Comment: Seems you are missing one closing ')'

Comment: Does this answer your question? [mysqli\_fetch\_assoc() expects parameter / Call to a member function bind\_param() errors. How to get the actual mysql error and fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22662488/mysqli-fetch-assoc-expects-parameter-call-to-a-member-function-bind-param)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **correct** syntax:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Mitglied 
WHERE 
    Vorname IN ('value1', 'value2')
OR
    Name IN ('value1', 'value2')
```

Comment: thank you so much, no idea why i didn´t get that myself